# Symfony2: isGranted method returns AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a Twig extension menu in my page, but i need use isGranted method to display the menu items according to the user, but symfony2 profilers shows me an alert:

The profilers says:

> AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
>
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\galvez_motos\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 2395
>   at SecurityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') in C:\xampp\htdocs\galvez_motos\src\GalvezMotos\AlmacenBundle\Twig\MenuExtension.php line 432

How can i use the isGranted method before login?

security.yml:

```
security:
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: GalvezMotos\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

encoders:
    GalvezMotos\AlmacenBundle\Entity\Usuario:
        algorithm: sha1
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false
```

Pd: Images

[image]

[image]

[image]